# Trying to call a function using application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) at app startup

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, storekit, swiftystorekit

I am using SwiftyStoreKit Cocoapods for In App Purchases. The GitHub page mentions how Apple recommends to register a transaction observer as soon as the app starts. Apple says: Adding your app's observer at launch ensures that it will persist during all launches of your app, thus allowing your app to receive all the payment queue notifications.

Here is the link: https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit

SwiftyStoreKit supports this by calling `completeTransactions()` when the app starts:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
// see notes below for the meaning of Atomic / Non-Atomic
SwiftyStoreKit.completeTransactions(atomically: true) { purchases in
    for purchase in purchases {
        switch purchase.transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchased, .restored:
            if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                // Deliver content from server, then:
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
            }
            // Unlock content
        case .failed, .purchasing, .deferred:
            break // do nothing
        }
    }
}
return true }
```

The GitHub page goes on to say: Note that `completeTransactions()` should only be called once in your code, in `application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

I cannot figure out how to implement this. Can someone help?

Comment: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called only once in the app, so `completeTransactions()` will be called once automatically. What is your problem actually?

Comment: When I copy this code into my app delegate file I get an error: Use of unresolved identifier SwiftyStoreKit. I have downloaded all the cocoa pod files. Is this code not supposed to go inside my app delegate file?

Comment: I guess it's simple, you should import the SwiftyStoreKit at the top of your AppDelegate.

Comment: just `import SwiftyStoreKit` same as `import UIKit`

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot! lol. Thank you! Haha